# Special Use Of Generics In Typesript

Tags: node.js, typescript, generics

I have an `interface` like this:

```
interface TestInterface {
  foo: string;
  bar: boolean;
}
```

And I wrote a function like this:

```
function test<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T>(param: K, param2: T[K]) {
  ...
}
```

I want when I use this function like following:

```
test<TestInterface, '&&&'>('&&&', false);
```

when i'm typing, suggest keys of `TestInterface` to me instead of both `&&&` and if I selected `bar` then `param2` be the type of `boolean`.

How should I have such an output?

Comment: This is an IntelliSense "completion list" question but I'm not exactly understanding when you'd like to see keys of `TestInterface` suggested.  Is it when you are typing the second type parameter specification?  If so I don't think there is such a feature and you might be better off splitting `test()` into a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function which takes `T` and returns another function which infers `K`... [like this](https://tsplay.dev/N5EgPN).  If that works for you I might be able to type up an answer; otherwise, please let me know what's missing.

Comment: I want the second type parameter corresponding to the first to be restricted when the first type parameter is selected

Comment: I mean if I selected `foo` as the first parameter, the second just be `foo` not anything else

Comment: There are two type parameters and two function parameters.. which "first" and "second" are you talking about?  Note that it is "restricted", since your above code [produces a compiler error](https://tsplay.dev/ND5ZRm), which tells you what you did wrong.  The part about IntelliSense I'm still not getting, and you might want to show a screenshot or something that demonstrates what you are and are not seeing (this might be one of the few times when images are necessary)

Comment: Excuse me, In my question, I have two `&&&` signs, OK? I want when I selected the first `&&&` as `foo`, The second `&&&` be `foo` too.
On the other hand, I want these keys to be suggested when I am typing.

Comment: @jcalz Did you understand me? `&&&` signs are just the blanks.

```test<TestInterface, '&&&'>('&&&', false);```

Comment: If you type `"foo"` for the second type parameter, then the first function parameter will indeed be restricted to `"foo`", and that value is suggested when typing the value of the first function parameter, as you can see [here](https://i.imgur.com/2EWD5ck.png).  Are you saying you want suggestions somewhere else?

Comment: I want when I'm typing "foo" for the second type parameter this key suggest me at the same time, and when I selected "foo", then the first function parameter will indeed be restricted to "foo".
That is, the suggestions are on the second type parameter, but the first function parameter is limited to the previous selection.